# JAVA array + scanner errors?

Tags: java

I'm doing a little program and I have a hard time using array and the scanner. I want the user to enter the number of games he played and then enter the number of games he finished. After, I want him to enter the number of time he took to finish each of his games.

I'm new to this and I'm really stuck now. I need to get the value of every single time the user took to finish a game because I need to apply some stats to it later.

I'm getting 2 errors!

Here's a bit of my code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class games {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many games have you played? (Limit of 10) : ");
        int gamesplayed = input.nextInt();input.nextLine();
        while ( gamesplayed < 0 || gamesplayed> 10 ) {
             System.out.println("This number is invalid!");
             System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("How many of these games have you finished? (Limit of 10) : ");
        int finishedgames = input.nextInt();input.nextLine();
        while ( finishedgames < 0 || finishedgames > 10 || gamesplayed < finishedgames ) {                
             System.out.println("This number is invalid!");
             System.exit(0);
        }
        int game = 1;
        int list[]=new int[game];
        while ( finishedgames+1 != game) 
        {
            System.out.print("How many time you took to finish your game " + game);System.out.println("?");
            list[game] = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();
            ++game;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help guys!

Comment: First thing to do: fix your indentation. The code you've posted is *horribly* hard to read due to the indentation being all over the place, and large numbers of pointless blank lines. Is your actual code like that, or was it just a problem with posting? Either way, you should fix the post.

Comment: What are the two errors you get and where?

Comment: Except last `while`, all other `while` can be replaced with `if`, of course that wont fix your problem though.

Comment: I think the problem is `int list[]=new int[game];`. This should be initialized with `gamesplayed`, like, `int list[]=new int[gamesplayed];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Games {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many games have you played? (Limit of 10) : ");
    String nextLine = input.nextLine();

    int gamesplayed = toInteger(nextLine);

    while (gamesplayed < 0 || gamesplayed > 10) {
        System.out.println("Wrong input, try again.");
        gamesplayed = toInteger(input.nextLine());
    }

    System.out.println(String.format(
            "How many of these games have you finished? (Limit of %d) : ",
            gamesplayed));
    nextLine = input.nextLine();
    int finishedgames = toInteger(nextLine);
    while (finishedgames < 0 || finishedgames >  gamesplayed ) {
        System.out.println("Wrong input, try again.");
        finishedgames = toInteger(input.nextLine());;
        if (finishedgames > gamesplayed) {
            System.out.print("Invalid Entry. ");
        }
    }

    int list[] = new int[finishedgames];
    for (int i = 0; i < finishedgames; i++){

        System.out.println(String.format("How many time you took to finish your game %d?", i + 1));
        int val = toInteger(input.nextLine());
        while (val == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            System.out.println("Wrong input, try again.");
            val = toInteger(input.nextLine());
        }
        list[i] = val;  
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(String.format("list[%d] = %d", i, list[i]));
    }
}

// Helper method that converts user entry to integer value
private static int toInteger(String nextLine) {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(nextLine);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return  Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First, please use if-statements instead of the two while loops.

The problem is this line: `int list[]=new int[game];`

The above line (`int game=1;`) sets the value of this variable to 1 so your int array can only store one elment.

You should use `int list[]=new int[finishedgames];` instead.

Also, consider to replace your last `while` loop with a `for` loop.

Edit:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class games {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many games have you played? (Limit of 10) : ");
    int gamesplayed = input.nextInt();input.nextLine();
    if ( gamesplayed < 0 || gamesplayed> 10 ) {
         System.out.println("This number is invalid!");
         System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println("How many of these games have you finished? (Limit of 10) : ");
    int finishedgames = input.nextInt();input.nextLine();
    if ( finishedgames < 0 || finishedgames > 10 || gamesplayed < finishedgames ) {                
         System.out.println("This number is invalid!");
         System.exit(0);
    }
    int list[]=new int[finishedgames];
    for (int i=0;i<list.length;i++) {
        System.out.println("How many time you took to finish your game " + (i+1) + "?");
        list[i] = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks but when I change it I still get the same 2 errors wich are games.java:74: error: ']' expected
                     int list[finishedgames] = input.nextInt();
                              ^
games.java:74: error: illegal start of expression
                     int list[finishedgames] = input.nextInt();
                                            ^
2 errors

Comment: It works, thanks! Now how can I call back all the time values that are in the list array? Thanks a lot

Comment: I just noticed that if I use list[i] * 2 it seems to work but I can't use it outside it's loop. Is there anyway I use it outside the loop? :)

Comment: To get a value out of an array use `list[0]` (This returns the first element stored in the array)

Comment: Ok but what I do if I want not only the first element stored but all of them? Thanks!

Comment: When I try list[0] it only print out 0 and not a value I entered.

Comment: to iterate through all elements use:
`for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
      System.out.println(list[0]); // Or whatever`

You can also use:

`for (int i : list)
    System.out.println(i);`

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class games {
      public static void main(String args[]) {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("How many games have you played? (Limit of 10) : ");
       int gamesplayed = input.nextInt();
       while ( gamesplayed < 0 || gamesplayed> 10 ) {
           System.out.println("This number is invalid!");
           gamesplayed = input.nextInt();
       }
       System.out.println("How many of these games have you finished? (Limit of 10) : ");
       int finishedgames = input.nextInt();
       while ( finishedgames < 0 || finishedgames > 10 || gamesplayed < finishedgames ) {
             System.out.println("This number is invalid!");
             finishedgames = input.nextInt();
       }
       int game = 1,Rem =finishedgames-gamesplayed ;
       int list[]=new int[Rem+1];
       while (Rem!=0) {
            System.out.println("How many time you took to finish your game " +game+"?");
            list[game] = input.nextInt();
            ++game;
            --Rem;
       }
   }
```

}